# How come the travelers from the future in 12 Monkeys are not carrying the virus?

Tags: 12-monkeys-2015

In the TV series *12 Monkeys* how come the travelers from the future (Cole, Ramse) are not carrying the virus? Although they are immune it doesn't mean their body doesn't have that virus or they cannot infect others.

Answer (score 3):

I've not seen much of the series at all, so answer based on medicine, not specifically this story.

Immunity means mounting an immune system response to an infection. In many cases, this does mean clearing the organism entirely from your system; in other cases it can still linger.

Other people can carry a disease without becoming symptomatic (Typhoid Mary) - they spread the disease without (necessarily) knowing that they do so.

Entirely possible for Cole and Ramse to be immune and not harbour the virus.